# Code doesn't download the file correctly

Tags: c#

I am trying to download IronPython with c#.

The original filesize = 15,6MB but when I click to download it gets a file which size is 16KB.

This is my download code:

```
string[] a = lsrv.GetLinks();
string iron = a[0].ToString();

//here is my string iron = http://ironpython.codeplex.com/downloads/get/970325

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
      wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
      wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(iron),
                 "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\IronPython-2.7.5.msi");
}
```

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't seem to be waiting for the download to finish...

Comment: Does a web installer version also exists?

Comment: The link you use only points to a HTML file that redirects to the actual download. Open the downloaded 16kb file with a text editor, does it contain HTML? If yes, the WebClient doesn't follow the redirect and you need to provide the correct URL.

Comment: DownloadFile[Async](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_communication)

Comment: It is downloading quickly and messagebox show me Download complete but when I go to the folder and click on the downloaded file,Microsoft says  like "it is not a correct format or source" I cannot correctly download 15,1MB of file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually downloading the file, but the page that starts the download.

CodePlex uses a strange download javascript method. The real file is situated here: http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=ironpython&DownloadId=970325&FileTime=130623736019230000&Build=21031.

If you put that in, the file will actually download.

Comment: so many thanks Patrick.I have changed the link and it downloaded 15,6MB that correct file.Great!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the HTML in question, you'll see that it starts downloading via Javascript. This code doesn't get executed by merely downloading the web page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        startDownload();
    });
</script>
```